# Alpinejs is not working for Modal only for Sidebar Menu

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am building a site with Laravel, tailwind css and alpinejs. I have a mobile navigation which is a offcanvas  sidebar and a modal shopping cart. The responsive mobile menu works fine but I can not figure out why the modal is not showing:

Layout.blade.php which blade components are placed in :

```
<body class="bg-[#F8F3F0]" >
    <div x-data="{ open: false, opencart: false }" @keydown.window.escape="open = false">
        <x-home.cart />
        <x-home.mobilenav />

        <div class="w-full hexnoisegrad h-[700px]">
            ...
            <x-home.nav />
...
```

In the home.nav component we have buttons that trigger the menu and modal:

```
...
<button type="button"
        class=" ..."
        @click="open = true">
        <span class="sr-only">Open sidebar</span>
        <x-icon.menu />
</button>

<button type="button"
        class=" ..."
        @click="opencart = true">
        <span class="sr-only">Open Cart</span>
        <x-icon.bag/>
</button>
```

In the home.mobilenav component we have:

```
<div dir="rtl" x-show="open" class="fixed inset-0 flex z-40 lg:hidden"
  x-description="Off-canvas menu for mobile, show/hide based on off-canvas menu state." x-ref="dialog"
  aria-modal="true">
...
```

And finally in the home.cart (modal) component we have:

```
<div x-data="{ opencart: false }" @keydown.window.escape="opencart = false" x-show="opencart" class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" x-ref="dialog" aria-modal="true">
...
```

I don't know why but Menu works fine and Modal (Shopping Cart) is not!
I think somehow it can not access "opencart" to check for the x-show.
If I change the x-data of cart component to:

```
 x-data="{ opencart: true}"
```

Modal will open correctly for the first time but after closing the button won't make it appear again.
I Also have drop downs that are working fine with alpine.

Very sorry for long post and taking your time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know alpinejs at all... But [their documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data) says the `x-data` directive is available to all element children... That seems to be meaning *"not to self"*... Try adding a wrapper div to hold the `x-data` only.

Comment: It worked!!!!
I removed the x-data from the cart and it remain only in the main wrapper as you said and it worked! Thank you!!! <3

Comment: For a very first question, it was very well formatted. I'm upvoting it, just for that. ;) Please accept the answer below (green checkmark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpinejs documentation indicates

> Properties defined in an x-data directive are available to all element children. <sup>[ref](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/data)</sup>

That implies a parent/child relation between the elements holding `x-data` and `x-show`.

So try adding a wrapper div to hold `x-data` only.

```
<div x-data="{ opencart: false }">
  <div @keydown.window.escape="opencart = false" x-show="opencart" class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto" x-ref="dialog" aria-modal="true">
  ...
</div>
```